# Static UITableView inside ContainerView not Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

A `UIViewcontroller` has a titleView at the top, an `UIContainerView`which manage 2 `TableviewController`, and the last item is an `UISegmentedControl` which is used to change between `LoginTableViewController` and `RegisterTableViewController` which have 15 cells, so it's needed scroll on them.

`LoginTableViewController` and `RegisterTableViewController` are **Statics** Table Views but can't scroll, that means that if I Scroll it, it will immediately returns to the top.

Also I have another `ViewController` which has a `containerView` with a `UITableViewController` inside but it isn't static and it can scroll.

Here is my code of **segmenteControlAction**

```
@IBAction func selectTab(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let nextViewController: UITableViewController!
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            let loginViewC = LoginTableViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
            loginViewC.isPresentingFromMenu = isPresentingFromMenu
            nextViewController = loginViewC
            break
        default:
            let regiterViewC = RegisterTableViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
            regiterViewC.isPresentingFromMenu = isPresentingFromMenu
            nextViewController = regiterViewC
            break
        }

        if let currentViewController = currentViewController{
            currentViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            currentViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            currentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        }
        currentViewController = nextViewController

        addChildViewController(currentViewController!)
        containerView.addSubview(currentViewController!.view)
        currentViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Do you know what I'm missing ?

**EDITED**

If I set the `tableViewController`which has 15 cells as embed view of ContainerView, the scroll works, but when I change the childViews in the container the scroll don't works